# XML serialization of references

Tags: java, xml, serialization, reference

I am writing a game which has a set of rules which should be loaded or saved from/to an XML file.

I have a **UnitType** class which can serialize and deserialize itself. 
I also have a **Faction** class which can load/save to XML.
And I have a **Rules** class which contains

```
UnitType[] unitTypes;
Faction[] factions
```

When loading the rules, I first load all unit types objects and store their references into `unitTypes` Then I load Factions and store references to them into `factions`;

However, `Faction` class also has a member array `UnitType[] accessibleUnitTypes`, which shows which unit types this faction can build, and I need to load it, too.

Here comes the problem: since a reference is just an address, serializing it makes no sense (and also is impossible in Java), so I need to create a special field `long ID` inside the `UnitType` class and a special **Manager** class which has a method `getUnitTypeByID(long ID)`. From now on, each time I create a `UnitType` object, I need to register it within the `Manager` (`Manager` has a `HashMap<Long, UnitType>` which maps IDs to the objects).

Now comes the problem that in java I can't explicitly delete objects. I can unregister the object from the `Manager` inside the `finalize()` method but since the reference to the object is still in the `Manager`, `finalize()` will never be called.

This makes me write another method `onDeleting()` inside `UnitType`, which should be called like `delete` in C++ each time the object is no longer needed. The `onDeleting()` method would then tell `Manager` to delete the reference to the object.

In the example above I mentioned only one class needing `onDeleting()` method, but say, I have a whole heirarchy of classes, and all of them need to serialize and deserialize themselves to XML.

I end up with the necessity to add `onDeleting()` method to any such class, and make sure that inside this method any memeber variables run their `onDeleting()` and so on. This now looks much like C++ where you'd call delete on pointers. This is probably not the Java way to do this. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually depends on how you do the XML<->Java mapping. If you use JAXB, you can use @XmlID / @XmlIDRef. If you roll your own, look into IdentityHashMap, and just generate back-references.

Comment: +1 - For more info on @XmlID/@XmlIDREF check out:  http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use one of the many XML serialization libraries rather than trying to solve all those problems all over again for yourself, and believe me you haven't found them all yet. Java.beans.XMLEncoder, XML Beans, JAXB, ...